# how can I save user ID on Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello I am newbie.

// Framework 6.9.0

```
$id = id();  // user id 
public function store(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|max:100',
        'description' => 'required',
        'user_id' => $id
    ]);

    CRUD::create($data);

    return redirect('/')->with('success', 'test is successfully saved');
}
```

'user_id' => $id   Is it possible ?  how can I insert a "user id" in TABLE

I will be waiting for your response !

Comment: yes, this should works, if you have a column named 'user_id' in your table, do you?
are you using backpack?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default authentication system, you can use the `Auth` facade.

```
'user_id' => Auth::id()
```

and add this line at the top of your controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Also, remove this line:

```
$id = id();
```

Comment: after fix my code , I got the Error -        array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array

Comment: Where do you get this error? I think it must be in your controller. Check the error log and find the corresponding line.